# Vue SPA multiple tabs with JWT (token expiration)

Tags: vue.js, tabs, jwt, token, single-page-application

I have a problem with my SPA Vue App.

I've built a really nice SPA with Vue :D one of its goodness is a cute carousel (managed by Vue, Axios and [VueGallerySlideshow](https://github.com/KitchenStories/vue-gallery-slideshow)). All using **JWT** beacause users must be logged to see images.

Now I have to implement a tricky functionality: **Opening a new tab when accessing the carousel**.

The problem is, when user opens a new tab, **the token gets refreshed in the new tab** while the old tab's token gets expired...

So, I don't know what is the correct way to achive this. Any ideas?

Thx!

Comment: Where are you storing tokens? Are you using a server? This makes me think you're storing tokens in memory and not in local storage or cookies, etc..

Comment: Yes! That was the problem, when storing in memory, new tab were forced to refresh token... Storing the token (and its ttl) in Cookies was the solution, by this way, each tab can share same token.

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Comment: Hi @Zalo, I am also encountering this problem. you did switch from storing to memory to cookie? . Storing it on memory is the recommended secure way as of now.

Comment: Hi, yes I used Cookies with ttl because this was the only way I found that let me share information between browser tabs...